# how to Manage Free version?

Tags: android, svn

I have just released my first app and would like to have a free version to it as well. I was wondering how should I manage my free version branch (in svn) so that it's easy to merge changes from full version? is it possible to just change package name in Manifest file? or do the package names have to be different in code? If so how could I Merge Changes easily?

Thanks, Jason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Android Library Project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject) is your friend here.

Answer (score 2):

I use this in all my apps :

```
public static final boolean LITE_VERSION = true;
```

then use it to disable some features.

It's important to know that the java compiler will ignore any piece of code in a if (!LITE_VERSION) block if LITE_VERSION is set to true, so it can't be reverse engineered (you can test it with the "javap -c" command).

Comment: Cool thanks, but that still leaves me with the package name problem, what do you do about that?

Comment: well.. it also leaves you with the problem of licensing. Free version cannot be licensed. Library is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to maintain a different branch to create a free version?
I would use the same code base and disable some features in the free version, either by `#ifdef` or configuration parameters.

Comment: But I can't post the same package name apk twice in the market anyways could I?

Comment: @Jason, I don't know android development, but can't you just keep a separate copy of the file where the package name is defined?

Comment: If it is only in the manifest then yea, but if I need to change the code package then that might be a problem I was suggested to make a fake package and just change the manifest file to that fake package that might work will let you know if it does

Answer (score 0):

I use Ant for builds.  I previously documented [how I build two versions of the same app](http://blog.uncommons.org/2010/07/19/building-two-versions-of-the-same-android-app/).  The last section where I discuss how to deal with differing manifests is probably of most interest to you.

Comment: Seems interesting will read this when I get home tomorrow, does this method allow for disabling cretin features though?

Comment: Cretin features? :)  I use different manifest files for each version.  I've also set-up three source trees (main, demo and common) and use Ant to merge two of the three trees (main+common or demo+common) into a single tree before building.

Answer (score 0):

I try to use the same codebase and package name and offer a premium key, which could be an extra App (apk) or just a serial number. This approach has the positive sideeffect that users who want to upgrade can use their old data and settings. The key just enables a flag like mention before which enables features dynamically